# Use refresh token cookie in nextauth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I used to have a custom implementation of authentication on my website. I use NestJs as backend, when I login, the backend response with access token, set the refresh token as http only cookie restricted on the refresh path and once the access Token has expires it will refresh the access token. Now that I use NextAuth, Nest can't set the cookie anymore. I was wondering what is the best practice for the refresh token ? Should I transfer the cookie to the front ?

Doesn't bother me to change the logic and backend, just want the most secure and best practice.

Answer (score 0):

> Now that I use NextAuth, Nest can't set the cookie anymore

Nest will send the cookie to the browser. and since you are using next you will at some point send Requests from inside `getStaticProps` or `getServerSidePros` but those functions are running on the server so they do not have any relation with the browser therefore they will not send back the cookie.

what I sugesst is to also send your `refreshToken` in the `response` and store both in next-auth `session` so you can access them from wherever you want inside your next app using `useSession()`

> Doesn't bother me to change the logic

not a lot

> just want the most secure and best practice

storing JWT tokens securely in the browser is impossible. see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&t=2618s)